# Citing mailing lists in paper

Tags: publications

How do i cite a particular conversation in a public mailing list in my paper?

[Background]
In a paper I am writing one of the protocol used was suggested on a mailing list pertaining to that software. In retrospect it was trivial, but yet not simple enough for beginner. Hence I want to cite that particular conversation. I have read papers where it is simply mentioned "In private communication" or equivalent.
Which does not feel right.

Is there something like zendo for citing mailing lists?

Comment: You need to provide some more information for us to be able to help you. Which journal are you submitting to? Do their guidelines demand a certain citation style? If not, which citation style do you want to use?

Comment: Usually any journal in American chemical society or American institute of Physics. I was just asking if there any "good practices" to cite such communications which are available publicly. Rather than some "personal communication" cite tag. Could not find any general guidelines in journal guide regarding such mailing lists

Comment: if the list has an online archive, I would cite that similar to a webpage.

Comment: APA and BlueBook have specific instructions for citing an email list discussion. I realize neither of those two styles will be applicable for your paper, but they might give you some ideas if the style required by the journals in your discipline does not cover citing email list discussions.

Comment: Put a note in the acknowledgements: "XX wants to thank YY for initially suggesting the use of protocol ZZ."

Comment: Comment by Karl seems the best way to do.